# NodeJS : How to migrate data from master table to two tables in the same order as master having as much async code as possible

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await

Will this be done by using promises or async/await ?

For example:
if master table is (id, uuid, op_1, op_2) 
then tables should be
table1(id, uuid) 
table2(id, op_1, op_2)

Table 1 & 2 having same order as master table is priority with as much async code as possible.

Comment: `Will this be done by using promises or async/await ?` - don't know, you haven't done anything

Comment: it is async....typing error

Comment: i can handle mysql part but very new to nodejs...just want to know the approach to the problem

Comment: `with as much async code as possible` the amount of async code depends on how the data for these "tables" is retrieved ... no need to force asynchrony where it isn't needed just so you can use a new toy *async/await* - once you have any asynchrony, then you'll need to deal with it appropriately - but as you've shown no code, and only just mentioned mysql, the answer is a pineapple

Comment: have been asked in assignment to try and make the code as much async as possible

Comment: well ... so far you've shown no code, so it looks like a "write the code for me" type question - how can anyone help with your code (you say you can handle the mysql part) if there's no code to help with - whoever asked the assignment is not fit to teach, in my opinion. A phrase like that is totally ridiculous - don't introduce asynchrony where it isn't required

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases that we should migrate data, like splitting a big data in one table into multiple tables or sync the production data to local, etc...

Here is my solution:

- keep syncing data from the original table every 10 seconds(create a task into crontab) and it won't be more than 1k items each time.
- sync data in positive sequence and store the latest id into Redis.

Here are some of the codes for you:

```
var maxMigrateId = 0;
redis.get(maxMigrateIdKey, function (err, result) {
  if(err){
    console.error("[ERROR] - "+err)
  }
  if(result){
    maxMigrateId = result;
  }
  console.log('MaxMigrateId: ' + maxMigrateId);
      mysql_read_pool.query("select id , uuid from {your original table} where id > ? limit 1000", [maxMigrateId], function (err, results) {
        if(err){
          throw err;
        }
        console.log('[Query Result Length] - ' + results.length);
        var migratePromises = []
        migratePromises.push(migrateData(results, mysql_write_pool_prod))
        Promise.all(migratePromises).then(()=>{
          redis.set(maxMigrateIdKey, maxMigrateId);
          console.log('finished');
          process.exit();
        }).catch((err)=>{
          console.log('Error: '+err);
        })
      });
});

function async migrateData(items, write_pool){
      var sql = "insert into ${your target table} (id, uuid) values"
      var dataValues = []
      items.forEach((data)=>{
        var list = [data.id, data.uuid];
        var val = "('" + list.join("','") + "')";
        dataValues.push(val);
      });
      sql += dataValues.join(',');
      return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
          write_pool.query(sql, [], function (error, results, fields) {
              if (error){
                reject(error);
              }
              resolve(true)
          });
      });
}
```